# Mobile Site development

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am planning to revamp my Mobile Site and to give my customers a better performance both in the UI as well as functionalities I preferred to go with Angular 2 for UI and Node.js as my back end component.

I searched on Google and came to know about Ionic 2 which is a platform for building hybrid apps and it gels well with Angular 2 framework.
Now I have 2 questions :

1. Can I use Angular + Ionic for my mobile site development or Ionic to be used only for developing Hybrid Apps?
2. Can I use Progressive Web Application for my new mobile site?

Which one well suits for developing a Mobile site?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ionic framework. Ionic 2 uses Angular 2 and it has an out of the box support for deploying as a website, as well as PWA support. See the [official announcement](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-pwa-support-in-ionic-2/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the details. One more question. My mobile site is currently non HTTPS and for PWA people are saying that HTTPS is must. Is HTTPS mandatory for the complete site for the PWA migration

Comment: Yes. See the official docs as to why: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/encrypt-in-transit/why-https

Comment: Thanks Nikola. Planned to go with Ionic2 + Angular2 for my PWA. But when I checked Ionic official site its been stated on the price page that - Free for apps on development / predictable price that scales. Is Ionic is a licenced product or an open source one

Comment: What you were looking at was their Ionic cloud pricing and it has nothing to do with the open source Ionic framework. I mean, you can ping them about it if you don't feel I'm credible to answer that ;)
So, Ionic framework is open source (http://ionicframework.com/), Ionic Cloud is not: http://ionic.io/. You don't need Ionic Cloud at all to make a full fledged app.

Answer (score 2):

Ionic applications are build with the same techniques and frameworks you could use for building a web app, like Angular 2, HTML and CSS. It is certainly possible to just deploy the app you build with Ionic as a web site so it can be viewed directly in the (mobile) browser, without needing to install a mobile app.

A web app cannot make use of Cordova plugins to interact with the native mobile functionality of course, keep that in mind.

Take a look at the Ionic documentation about progressive web apps: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/progressive-web-apps/

Also check which browser versions you need to support, as Ionic doesn't support older browsers: http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/#browser-support